# Azure powershell : find which principal created or modified a given principal

Tags: azure, powershell, delta, spn

I need to find which principal has modified or created a given principal.

We can have the list of modified principals using the Microsoft Graph Api:

https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/servicePrincipals/delta

I want to find the creator of this modification/creation for each modified principal

Thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can get the information of the owner of service principle

```
$ServicePrincipalId = (Get-AzureADServicePrincipal -Top 1).ObjectId
Get-AzureADServicePrincipalOwner -ObjectId $ServicePrincipalId
```

The Get-AzureADServicePrincipalOwner cmdlet gets the owners of a service principal in Azure Active Directory (AD).

result would be something like below

[image]

Here is how you can get more details on this.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/get-azureadserviceprincipalowner?view=azureadps-2.0

Hope it helps.